# React Hook error when loading Solid webId profile

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, solid

I'm trying to use [Solid](https://solid.github.io/react-components/)'s `react-components` to load a user's profile from their `webId`. I'm running into a problem with `useLDflex()`. There problem seems to be something to do with React Hooks, but I can't figure it out. My goal is to load the user's profile when the page loads; open to making whatever changes necessary. I'm using MobX for state.

Below is the code and below below is the error in the compiler/web browser. Thank you.

Code (React/JSX/TypeScript):

```
    import React from 'react';    // 16.14.0
    import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
    import { observable } from 'mobx';
    import { useLDflex } from '@solid/react';    // 1.10.0

    @observer
    export class Profile extends React.Component<{profileId: string}, {}> {
        @observable webId = `https://${this.props.profileId}.solidcommunity.net/profile/card#me`;
        @observable name = useLDflex(`[${this.webId}`)[0];

        render() {
            return (
                <main role="Profile">
                    <div className="container">
                        webId: https://{this.props.profileId}.solidcommunity.net/profile/card#me
                        Name: {this.name}
                    </div>
                </main>
            )
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
src/components/profile/index.tsx
  Line 9:24:  React Hook "useLDflex" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Convert this component to `functional component`. Because `useLDflex` is a custom hook and hook just only used inside functional

Comment: Solved. Solution using HOC posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467419/react-higher-order-component-solid-useldflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use React Hooks inside class component, ref here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

So you need to rewrite it to `functional component` with Mobx, or make a `higher order component` and pass the props into your class component (when your class is too complex to rewrite)

- With FC:

```
import {observer} from "mobx-react";

const Profile = observer(({ profileId }) => {
  // ...
  const name = useLDflex(`...`);
  // ...
})
```

- HOC

```
const withName = (Component) => ({ profileId }) => {
  const name = useLDflex('...');
  return <Component name={name} profileId={profileId} />
}
export default withName(Profile);
```

Comment: Could you fill out the commented sections of the FC code? I still can't figure it out. Where is the `export` and the `return`?

Comment: it is same as class component, "export default Post" and "return <main>...</main>"

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. Posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467419/react-higher-order-component-solid-useldflex

Comment: Solved. Solution using HOC posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467419/react-higher-order-component-solid-useldflex