# React: Higher-Order Component: Solid useLDflex()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components, solid

I'm struggling with a Higher-Order Component in React. I'm trying use use [Solid](https://solid.github.io/react-components/)'s `react-components` to load a user's profile data with `useLDflex()`. My code is throwing an error that I can't understand; I'm not sure if the problem relates to React, Higher-Order Components, or Solid's library. Can anyone help?

Code (React/TSX):

```
import { useLDflex } from '@solid/react';
import React from 'react';

class Profile extends React.Component<{name: string}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <main role="Profile">
                <div className="container">
                    Name: {this.props.name}
                </div>
            </main>
        )
    }
}

interface IProfileId {
    profileId: string;
}

const withName = (Component: any) => ({profileId}: IProfileId) => {
    const webId = `https://${profileId}.solidcommunity.net/profile/card#me`;
    const [name, namePending, nameError] = useLDflex(`[${webId}].name`);
    return <Component name={name} />
}

export const newProfile = withName(Profile);
```

Error (on  line):

```
Error: Specify at least one term when calling .next() on a path
```

Comment: I tried recreating the problem, but didn't get that error on my end. So, I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that error is being caused by the code you have here.

Also, I did have to change `export const newProfile` to `export const NewProfile` in order to get it imported and rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The problem was that `name` was in an unknown/undefined state while the profile was being loaded from the Solid server. Here's the working code:

```
import { useLDflexValue } from '@solid/react';
import React from 'react';

class P extends React.Component<{name: string}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <main role="Profile">
                <div className="container">
                    Name: {this.props.name}
                </div>
            </main>
        )
    }
}

const withName = (Component: any) => ({profileId}: {profileId: string}) => {
    const webId = `https://${profileId}.solidcommunity.net/profile/card#me`;
    const name = useLDflexValue(`[${webId}].name`)?.toString() || 'loading...';
    return <Component name={name} />
}

export const Profile = withName(P);
```